# Does the observation that we can raise finite dimensional vector spaces to the power of certain hyperbolic numbers teach us anything?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, split-complex-numbers

($U^*$ denotes the dual space of $U$ whenever $U$ is a vector space. I'll work over $\mathbb{R}$ for simplicity)

Given a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ and a hyperbolic number $a + bj$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, lets define $$V^{a + bj} := V^a \times (V^b)^*.$$

This is the only such function satisfying $V^0 \cong \mathbb{R}, V^1 \cong 1, V^j \cong V^*, V^{x+y} \cong V^x \times V^y.$ As a nice bonus, we get $(V^x)^y \cong V^{xy}$, suggesting that the usual multiplication of hyperbolic numbers is the "correct" multiplication for this application.

> **Question.** Does this give us anything / teach us anything?

Comment: Can you say more about what you have in mind? I assume the reason you call this a hyperbolic number and not just a pair of numbers is the observation that we have $(V^n)^m \cong V^{nm}$ because taking duals is involutive (on f.d. vector spaces).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, well, for example, the usual quadratic form on the hyperbolic plane is $N(x+yj) = x^2 - y^2$, making $|x + yj| := \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$ a reasonable definition, where both sides of this expression are to be though of as living in $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{C})$. Following this line of thought, this suggests, for example, that the "size" of $\mathbb{R}^4$ is $\pm 4$, whereas the "size" of $\mathbb{R}^3 \times \mathbb{R}^*$ is $\sqrt{9 - 1} = \pm 2 \sqrt{2}$. My question is roughly: does this kind of thinking go anywhere?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, well, thanks for your honesty :)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm also interested in the underlying category theory of $V^a \times (V^b)^*$, by the way. Obviously, this isn't a functor on the usual category f.d. vector spaces due to contravariance. There's a boring way to fix this problem by moving the core of f.d. vector spaces, but I'd be interested to know if instead we can usefully regard $V \mapsto V^a \times (V^b)^*$ as a lax functor $\mathbb{R}\mathbf{Mod} \rightarrow \mathrm{Span}(\mathbb{R}\mathbf{Mod}).$ If so, my next question is whether we can characterize the lax functors that arise from hyperbolic numbers in this way...

Comment: ... without mentioning the hyperbolic numbers, just based on the properties of the lax functors.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'll remark that the endomorphism construction can be regarded as a lax functor $\mathrm{End} : \mathbf{Set} \rightarrow \mathrm{Span}(\mathbf{Set})$ by declaring that if $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is a function between sets, then $\mathrm{End}(f) : \mathrm{End}(X) \nrightarrow \mathrm{End}(Y)$ is the relation defined by $(\alpha,\beta) \in \mathrm{End}(f) \iff f \circ \alpha = \beta \circ f.$